# Inserting one matrix as an element of another matrix using Numpy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, mapping

I'm using Numpy and have a 7x12x12 matrix whose values I would like to populate in 12x12 chunks, 7 different times. Suppose I have these 12x12 matrices:

```
first_Matrix
second_Matrix
third_Matrix
... (etc)
seventh_Matrix = first_Matrix + second_Matrix + third_Matrix...
```

that I'd like to add to:

```
grand_Matrix
```

How can I do this? I assume there is a better way than loops that map the coordinates from one matrix to the next, and if there's not, could someone please write out the code for mapping first_Matrix into the first 12x12 element of grand_Matrix?

Comment: It's worth noting that wherever you have `first_...`, `second_...`, ... it's a sign of bad design. I'm not sure if that was just for example, but if not, then use a data structure like a list.

Comment: t'was, indeed, just for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grand_Matrix[0,...] = first_Matrix
grand_Matrix[1,...] = second_Matrix
```

and so on.

Anyway, as @Lattyware commented, it is a bad design to have extra names for so many such homogenous objects.

If you have a list of 12x12 matrices:

```
grand_Matrix = np.vstack(m[None,...] for m in matrices)
```

`None` adds a new dimension to each matrix and stacks them along this dimension.

Comment: Why `,...`? Wouldn't simply `grand_Matrix[0] = first_Matrix` do the trick?

Comment: @sven explicit is better than implicit. The `...` makes it clearer that this is not just a 1D array and I think is a better notation.

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- I like the ellipsis.  I think it makes it a little more clear that grand_Matrix is a numpy array instead of a list or something.  To be even a little more explicit, `grand_Matrix[0,:,:]=first_Matrix` would also work.

Comment: vstack! That seems like the thing I'm searching for.Can you explain "None" is that line?  and I assume 'matrices' is the list of matrices and not something python/numpy inherently understands?

Comment: @HenryGomersall: How does it make clear this is not a 1D array?  The code would also work on a 1D array even with the ellipsis.  The version given by mgilson is indeed more explicit.

Comment: @SvenMarnach because if it was a 1D array, you wouldn't do that. Python is full of ways in which you can confuse through misleading code, but we don't do that ;) I agree with you re mgilson's point.

Comment: @wagras - compare `first_Matrix.shape` with `first_Matrix[None,...].shape`.